# Complete Uninstall from your android phone

Tags: uninstall

Guys! I need to completely uninstall linux Ubuntu from my android  phone, tried searching the net, all futile. Hoping I hear from all the techie and geeks out here. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a complete uninstall, I'd recommend reflashing your android rom. The reflashing process really depends on your phone model.

Comment: For a complete uninstall, I'd recommend reflashing your android rom. The reflashing process really depends on your phone model.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about a version of Ubuntu phone which you flashed onto your device, then you need to flash android back onto your device. You may need to get the appropriate tools and image for doing so, from your device manufacturer.

Comment: Thanks Dobey! Much appreciated! Cheers mate! –  Nerino Pinto yesterday